# -mouseUp event is sometimes being passed to the wrong view

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mouseevent, nsevent

I think a bit of a head-scratcher?

Basically we have this inconsistent bug, where one of our custom controls (a switch) receives a `-mouseUp` event, without receiving the `-mouseDown`, but the kicker is that the mouse location isn't anywhere near the switch in the first place

Specifically it's happening after:

- Right click to open context menu  (not anywhere near the switch)
- Left click somewhere to close context menu (not anywhere near the switch)

Here is the callstack:
[image]

Notice the event is directly passed to our custom control

I have already tried playing with `-acceptsFirstMouse:` and `-acceptsFirstResponder` to no avail

I have also confirmed that the switch is **not** in the responder chain

I have put in this code into `-mouseUp:`:

```
if( !NSPointInRect( [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil], [self bounds] ) )
{
    return;
}
```

which successfully breaks out when the `-mouseUp` is received and the mouselocation isn't on the switch.

But it just seems funny, like I'm missing something here

How could the switch be receiving the `-mouseUp`?

Comment: Is the switch a subclass of `NSControl`? Which methods did you override? Which view handles the context menu?

Comment: I would try setting a breakpoint on that _reallySendEvent:... method and step through the assembly to see if you can figure out what it's doing.  But that's just me.  :->